# Python Pandas - Detect Column and number format

Tags: python, pandas

Im using Pandas to manage csv.
Unfortunally I have columns with number that use "comma" as decimal separator:

Es. 50,12

When I use convert_dtypes() function, this columns are converted to String and not number so the sort functions doesn't work properly.

Is there a way to specify "number format" of dataset so every number is considered like NNNN,DD instead of NNNN.DD

EXAMPLE:

```
| Gross Amount | Item Number|
-----------------------------
|52,50         |   1       |
|498,00        |   2       |
|10,01         |   3       |
|1,74          |   4       |
|518,04        |   5       |
|2,10          |   6       |
```

AutoDetect return this:

```
Gross Amount     string
Item Number       Int64
```

So When I order by "Gross Amount" it sort String and not number so, for example, "10,01" is printed before "2,10"

Comment: Can you give an example for a data you have and what is your desired output?

Comment: If you want only to change the seperator from comma to dot you can do like that `df_name['column_name'].str.replace(',', '.').astype('float')`

Comment: Unfortunally I don't know which column will have numbers. I need some sort of master setting (or "locale" settings) on pandas reader so "every number has to match my pattern" .

Comment: so you want to replace the comma to dot(and convert to float) in all the column that are in this format: `NNNN,DD`?

Comment: Yeah, some sort. Some settings to tell pandas how to treat numbers

Comment: I don't think you can change pandas settings but you can create a function that search this format in the dataframe and convert it. I can prepere you a code that does that

Comment: It would be great!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239154/discussion-between-eitan-rosati-and-evisvil).

Answer (score 0):

When suppose the DataFrame is called `df`. you can use the code below.

**Code:**

```
for column in df.columns:
    if pd.api.types.is_string_dtype(df[column]):
        try:
            df[column] = df[column].str.replace(',', '.').astype('float')
        except:
            pass
```